# How to close the thread and exit to the command line?

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a very simple example, it prints out the names, but the problem is, when I press ctrl+C, the  program doesn't return to the normal command line interface:

```
^CStopping
```

After I only see my cursor blinking, but I can't do anything, so I have to close the window and open it up again.
I'm running Ubuntu 12.10.

that's my code:

```
import threading
import random
import time
import Queue
import urllib2
import sys

queue = Queue.Queue()
keep_running = True

class MyThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, queue):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.queue = queue
        self.names = ['Sophia', 'Irina', 'Tanya', 'Cait', 'Jess']

    def run(self):
        while keep_running:
            time.sleep(0.25)
            line = self.names[random.randint(0,len(self.names)-1)]
            queue.put(line)
            self.queue.task_done()

class Starter():
    def __init__(self):
        self.queue = queue
        t = MyThread(self.queue)
        t.start()
        self.next()

    def next(self):
        while True:
            time.sleep(0.2)
            if not self.queue.empty():
                line = self.queue.get()
                print line, self.queue.qsize()
            else:
                print 'waiting for queue'

def main():  
    try:
        Starter()     
        queue.join()
    except KeyboardInterrupt, e:
        print 'Stopping'
        keep_running = False
        sys.exit(1)

main()
```

Comment: Is an "Ubunut" someone who really loves Ubuntu? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your main problem is that you didn't declare `keep_running` as `global`, so `main` is just creating a local variable with the same name.

If you fix that, it will usually exit on some platforms.

If you want it to *always* exit on *all* platforms, you need to do two more things:

1. `join` the thread that you created.
2. protect the shared global variable with a `Lock` or other sync mechanism.

However, a shared global `keep_running` flag isn't really needed here anyway. You've already got a `queue`. Just define a special "shutdown" message you can post on the queue, or use closing the queue as a signal to shutdown.

While we're at it, unless you're trying to simulate a slow network or something, there is no need for that `time.sleep` in your code. Just call `self.queue.get(timeout=0.2)`. That way, instead of always taking 0.2 seconds to get each entry, it will take *up to* 0.2 seconds, but as little as 0 if there's already something there.

Comment: Awsemoe!!!!! So far only tried global keep_running - works like a charm. Will try all other suggestions as well! Thank you very much!

Comment: An idea with timeout is just brilliant

Answer (score 1):

Your main thread is stuck in `Starter.next`. The interrupt then is called there and propagates up to the first line of the `try` statement and is caught, jumping to the `except` clause before join can be called. Try putting the `join` call in a finally block (with the `sys.exit`) or simply moving it to th exception handler